# What is this red stalk plant?

Tags: identification, flowers

We have these all around the house we bought in fall. What are they? When should they flower?

The previous owners were great fans of bulbs and flower beds.

This is south east michigan.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4031/is-this-a-desirable-plant-or-a-weed

Answer (score 5):

Looks like Paeony to me, not sure which variety other than to say one of the herbaceous perennial types. Flowering time is usually late April and May here in the UK, but yours don't seem quite so well advanced, so maybe nearer June. Some varieties flower a little later, around late June/early July.

Comment: Yup. Definitely peony.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add... Peony flower heads get heavy and they tend to droop. They make supports for peonies which you might want to look into. They're also very susceptible to powdery mildew so you should keep an eye on that. I've had success with [neem on peonies](http://www.organiclawndiy.com/2013/08/controlling-powdery-mildew-with-neem-oil.html) with powdery mildew.

Otherwise fairly easy plants to take care of. At the end of the season, beginning of winter, cut the plants down to the ground. Rake away any debris and keep free of fallen leaf debris.

Comment: Reminds me, I have some sitting in a pot I need to find a spot for. That deep red that turns to a dark green leafage... Dug them out of the Blueberry bed for repurposing the growing area.

Comment: And *right now* would be a good time to get the support in place - easier than when the plant is fully grown.