# What is this plant and how do I care for it?

Tags: identification, flowers, shrubs, peonies

[image: Flower]
[image: Base of plant]

It's very fragrant. As you can hopefully see in the second photo, there are no thorns. The plant itself is looking a little out of control, like it could use some pruning. I'm just not sure how or when to go about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a [Peony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peony), a hardy perennial known for its fragrant blooms.

This plant is *not* in need of pruning, but in need of some support - these flowers may be heavy.
A typical solution are plant supports: Wire "rings" or semi circles on stakes that keep the plant from "flopping down", especially when blooms or heavy rain make them top heavy. The "grow-through" variety is sectioned within but must be put in place *before* the plants are tall like yours.
In a pinch, you can always use a few stakes and some string for support.

Peonies don't need much care: Don't plant them too deep or they won't flower (obviously not your problem), don't mulch at the base and fertilize with a good all-purpose fertilizer once or twice a year. You *can* cut spent blooms, but don't need to, the seed pods are sometimes quite attractive, too. (There is no accounting for taste, obviously.) In fall/winter the foliage will die back, leaving the spot bare, but it will re-grow in spring - surprising some unwitting gardeners like [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4031/is-this-a-desirable-plant-or-a-weed/4033#4033).

Enjoy your peony!