# Are these ants hurting my bush?

Tags: shrubs, pest-damage

These ants appear to be guarding the flower buds, are they? Or are they hurting it?

Also how do I stop the damage to these buds?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

No, the ants are not hurting the peony buds or plant in any way. See this [answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/18162/peony-and-ant-symbiotic-relationship/18174#18174) to a similar question for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The ants are fine, as already noted.

The shriveled bud may be an indicator of poor overall health in the plant, rather than "damage, as such" - I have some peonies in marginal locations that will produce "dud buds" like that - a half-hearted attempt that never makes it to being a flower. Of course, I don't know what your's looked like before this - there *might* be some sort of damage going on, but my experience suggests "improve soil and/or light condition for an overall healthier plant" as being the root cause for similar things that I see.

Though zooming in, that looks more "eaten" than I gathered in the zoomed out view.