# What type of red plant is this?

Tags: identification

Good Morning!!

I just bought a house, and I have lots of random things growing, and I have no clue what they are? This one is particularly vexing for me. It’s growing really fast (this pic is about two weeks in)

There is some evidence that a bush was cut down probably in the fall, and then these popped up from the ground. So I don’t know if it was dead and is coming back, or if I have to cut it every year, I wanted to research it so a name helps!!

[image]

Comment: I would wait few more weeks, before to try to do an identification. In my opinion the red is due just because of new shots, and later they will become green [not the most common way, but it is not seldom to have such red shots]. So if you have no answers in next days, you should add a new photos in few weeks.

Comment: I suspect it might be a paeony, but would  be good to see  another photo when the first leaves open

Comment: If it is a paeony (and I agree with that ID) it probably wasn't "cut down" - everything above ground dies naturally over winter. Clearing away the dead remains makes the garden look tidier, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely a bunch of peonies; they frequently come up with red stalks which then produce green leaves. You can find a number of previous questions about peonies on this site including [this one](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4031/is-this-a-desirable-plant-or-a-weed).

Comment: Flowers will be red,white or pink , no unusual care needed. It is normal for ants to be on the flower buds when they show up.  The ants don't do anything but hang-out. Japanese have developed many varieties because it is so popular there , but they are seldom seen at American homes.

Comment: @blacksmith37 - An FYI on prevalence of Itoh and tree peonies in my part of the US... Some Itoh's and intersectional peonies are EXTREMELY popular, especially the plants with "odd" color flowers, like Bartzella. Tree peonies sell out whenever offered in my area (current employer order 36 and had to restock for Mother's Day).

Comment: Morton Arboretum ( Chicago) had a large variety , but nothing in garden shops ( 1970's).